# Add tree command output into LyX document

Tags: lyx, dirtree

I need to add the following listing into LyX, but instead of having the following result, I obtain the one at bottom of this page. What can I do?

**How it should be**:

```
$ tree
.
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── res
│   ├── drawable-hdpi
│   │   ├── color_orange.png
│   │   ├── ic_action_new_note.png
│   │   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   │   ├── img_star.png
│   │   └── textlines.xml
│   ├── drawable-ldpi
│   ├── drawable-mdpi
│   │   ├── color_orange.png
│   │   ├── ic_action_new_note.png
│   │   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   │   └── img_star.png
│   ├── drawable-xhdpi
│   │   ├── color_orange.png
│   │   ├── ic_action_new_note.png
│   │   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   │   └── img_star.png
│   ├── drawable-xxhdpi
│   │   ├── color_orange.png
│   │   ├── ic_action_new_note.png
│   │   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   │   └── img_star.png
│   ├── layout
│   │   ├── activity_note_taker_main.xml
│   │   ├── change_color_fragment_layout.xml
│   │   ├── change_priority_fragment_layout.xml
│   │   ├── change_title_fragment_layout.xml
│   │   ├── list_layout.xml
│   │   ├── new_note_layout.xml
│   │   └── order_by_fragment_layout.xml
│   ├── menu
│   │   └── note_taker_main.xml
│   ├── values
│   │   ├── dimens.xml
│   │   ├── strings.xml
│   │   └── styles.xml
│   ├── values-it
│   │   └── strings.xml
│   ├── values-v11
│   │   └── styles.xml
│   ├── values-v14
│   │   └── styles.xml
│   └── values-w820dp
│       └── dimens.xml
└── src
    └── it
        └── panopticon
            ├── dialogs
            │   ├── ChangeColorDialog.java
            │   ├── ChangePriorityDialog.java
            │   ├── ChangeTitleDialog.java
            │   ├── OptionsDialog.java
            │   └── SortingDialog.java
            ├── notetaker
            │   ├── NewNoteActivity.java
            │   ├── NoteAdapter.java
            │   ├── Note.java
            │   └── NoteTakerMain.java
            └── utilities
                ├── Colors.java
                ├── NoteDBAdapter.java
                └── SortCriteria.java

39 directories, 133 files
```

**How is**:

> $ tree . ├── AndroidManifest.xml ├──
>   res │   ├── drawable-hdpi │   │   ├── color_orange.png │   │   ├──
>   ic_action_new_note.png │   │   ├── ic_launcher.png │   │   ├──
>   img_star.png │   │   └── textlines.xml │   ├── drawable-ldpi │   ├──
>   drawable-mdpi │   │   ├── color_orange.png │   │   ├──
>   ic_action_new_note.png │   │   ├── ic_launcher.png │   │   └──
>   img_star.png │   ├── drawable-xhdpi │   │   ├── color_orange.png │  
>   │   ├── ic_action_new_note.png │   │   ├── ic_launcher.png │   │   └──
>   img_star.png │   ├── drawable-xxhdpi │   │   ├── color_orange.png │  
>   │   ├── ic_action_new_note.png │   │   ├── ic_launcher.png │   │   └──
>   img_star.png │   ├── layout │   │   ├── activity_note_taker_main.xml
>   │   │   ├── change_color_fragment_layout.xml │   │   ├──
>   change_priority_fragment_layout.xml │   │   ├──
>   change_title_fragment_layout.xml │   │   ├── list_layout.xml │   │  
>   ├── new_note_layout.xml │   │   └── order_by_fragment_layout.xml │  
>   ├── menu │   │   └── note_taker_main.xml │   ├── values │   │   ├──
>   dimens.xml │   │   ├── strings.xml │   │   └── styles.xml │   ├──
>   values-it │   │   └── strings.xml │   ├── values-v11 │   │   └──
>   styles.xml │   ├── values-v14 │   │   └── styles.xml │   └──
>   values-w820dp │       └── dimens.xml └── src
>       └── it
>           └── panopticon
>               ├── dialogs
>               │   ├── ChangeColorDialog.java
>               │   ├── ChangePriorityDialog.java
>               │   ├── ChangeTitleDialog.java
>               │   ├── OptionsDialog.java
>               │   └── SortingDialog.java
>               ├── notetaker
>               │   ├── NewNoteActivity.java
>               │   ├── NoteAdapter.java
>               │   ├── Note.java
>               │   └── NoteTakerMain.java
>               └── utilities
>                   ├── Colors.java
>                   ├── NoteDBAdapter.java
>                   └── SortCriteria.java
>
> 39 directories, 133 files

Comment: Do you want to list it as source/verbatim? Have a look at the `listings` package. Otherwise, please post a complete, compilable document (Minimum Working Example).

Comment: How exactly did you add this?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.I selected `Insert->Code Listings`

Comment: Use Edit --> Paste Special --> Plain text to paste the text into the listing, otherwise line breaks are not preserved (similar to http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/6821). That isn't quite enough, as some unicode characters are used there. If you compile with XeTeX or LuaTeX it should work, but depending on font you may or may not get those characters in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the `dirtree` package.

1. In `Document`>`Settings`>`LaTeX preamble`, insert this code:

   ```
   \usepackage{dirtree}
   ```
2. In the main text, open an ERT box (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and write something like:

   ```
   \dirtree{%
   .1 Tree.
   .2 AndroidManifest.xml.
   .2 res.
   .3 drawable-hdpi.
   .4 color\_orange.png.
   }
   ```

The result must be the same that this MWE in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{dirtree}
\begin{document}
\dirtree{%
.1 Tree.
.2 AndroidManifest.xml.
.2 res.
.3 drawable-hdpi.
.4 color\_orange.png.
}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: 1) Is there a way to correctly go to a new page when the list is too long?

2) I suggest http://texblog.org/2012/08/07/semi-automatic-directory-tree-in-latex/

Comment: @Caterpillar See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6103/dirtree-pagebreak-issue helps

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, you need to use paste special, to keep the line breaks.

You may also wish to use a mono-spaced environment, like 'verbatim' or 'LyX-code' so that your "tree" characters line up. If so, begin a new paragraph, select one of the two mono-spaced styles and then paste special. For me, `ctl + shift + v` is a shortcut for paste special.

Comment: As he said, he inserted this into a listing (Insert --> Program listing).

Comment: Ah, missed that.